Freeze the position of figures
In my document, several subsections are composed of tables.
When compiling, I get the titles of the subsections in a row and then in the following pages the tables in a row: this therefore does not correspond to my sequence.


How can I freeze the positioning of my tables?
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{inputenc} 
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{enumitem}  %pour l'option [resume] qui permet de reprendre la numérotation
\usepackage{pifont}
%\usepackage{tabularx}
%\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath,booktabs,counter,diagbox,siunitx,varwidth}
\newcommand{\longeq}[1]{\begin{gathered}#1\end{gathered}}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{picinpar}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{xstring}
 \usepackage{caption}
 \usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelsep=newline,justification=centering}


\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{enumitem}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \chemmacros_load_module:n #1 {}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\usepackage{ghsystem}
\ghssetup{language=french}
\usepackage[ fullpath ="C:/Users/groir/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/isosafety" ]{isosafety}

\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{marvosym}

\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=black}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
\AtBeginDocument{\sbox0{$x$}}% to be sure the math fonts are computed
\tikzset{baseshift/.style={yshift=-\the\dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2}}

%\usepackage{lmodern}
\newenvironment{manip}{\begin{itemize}[label=\ding{45}]}{\end{itemize}}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikzsymbols}
\usepackage{moresize}

\usepackage[Rejne]{fncychap}

%\usepackage{pgf-spectra}


\newcommand{\atrf}{ \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(letter.base)]
    \node[
      draw,
      circle,
      inner sep=1pt,
      shade,
      shading=ball,
      circle,
      ball color=black!5!Peach,
      minimum width=2em,% <--- to get balls of the same width
    ] (letter) {\small ATRF};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\newcommand{\trf}{ \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(letter.base)]
    \node[
      draw,
      circle,
      inner sep=1pt,
      shade,
      shading=ball,
      circle,
      ball color=black!5!Aquamarine,
      minimum width=2em,% <--- to get balls of the same width
    ] (letter) {\small TRF};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\newcommand{\asi}{ \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(letter.base)]
    \node[
      draw,
      circle,
      inner sep=1pt,
      shade,
      shading=ball,
      circle,
      ball color=black!5!Orchid,
      minimum width=2em,% <--- to get balls of the same width
    ] (letter) {\small ASI};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

        
%Insérer l'équation/figure devant le numéro d'une équation/une figure
\newcommand{\eq}[1]{\hyperref[#1]{'équation \ref{eq:#1}}}
\newcommand{\fig}[1]{\hyperref[#1]{figure \ref{#1}}}

\newcommand*{\fullref}[1]{\hyperref[{#1}]{\autoref*{#1} \nameref*{#1}}} % One single link

\setlength{\parskip}{3ex plus 1ex minus 1ex}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
%\setcounter{secnumdepth}{6}

        \begin{document}
    \part{Sécurité}
        
    \chapter{Pictogrammes de sécurité}
    \section[Les différents types de pictogrammes (ATRF) (TRF) (ASI)]{Les différents types de pictogrammes \atrf \trf \asi}
    Pour les pictogrammes de sécurité ou d'information, une norme internationale (ISO 7010) définit le type de signal, leur couleur et leur forme. 
    
    La norme définit 5 types auxquels on peut ajouter le type de pictogramme lié au SGH (voir~\ref{sec:secu_chimie_general}) :
    
    \begin{table}[!h]
        \centering
        \begin{tblr}{
                vspan=even, hspan=minimal,
                colspec={Q[c,5cm] Q[c,2cm] Q[c,5cm] Q[c,2cm]}, rowspec={Q[m] Q[m] Q[m] Q[m] Q[m] Q[m] Q[m]},
                colsep=3pt,
                row{1}={cmd=\textbf},
            }
            \toprule[blue]
            Signaux & Couleur & Forme & Exemple \\
            \midrule[blue]
            chimie & rouge & losange & \adjustbox{valign=m}{\ghspic{acid}} \\
            interdiction & rouge  & cercle barré avec un trait &\adjustbox{valign=m}{ \includegraphics[width=1cm]{\Isosign{P022}}}\\
            obligation & bleu  & cercle &\adjustbox{valign=m}{ \includegraphics[width=1cm]{\Isosign{M001}}}\\
            avertissement ou signalisation de risque ou de danger & jaune & triangle équilatéral avec des coins arrondis & \adjustbox{valign=m}{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{\Isosign{W001}}}\\
            sauvetage et secours & vert & carré ou rectangle & \adjustbox{valign=m}{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{\Isosign{E001}}} \\
            lutte contre l'incendie & rouge & carré & \adjustbox{valign=m}{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{\Isosign{F001}}}\\
            \bottomrule[blue]
        \end{tblr}
        \caption{Pictogrammes dangers physiques}
        \label{tab:picto_danger_physique}
    \end{table}
    
    \section[Pictogrammes et pannneaux courants (ATRF) (TRF) (ASI)]{Pictogrammes et pannneaux courants \atrf \trf \asi} \subsection[Pictogramme de chimie]{Pictogramme de chimie}\label{ssec:picto_chimie}
    En chimie, le SGH (Système Général Harmonisé) associe 9 pictogrammes pour prévenir 3 types de danger (physique, pour la santé, pour l'environnement) :
    
        \begin{table}[!h]%
        \centering
        \begin{tblr}{
                vspan=even, hspan=minimal,
                colspec={Q[c] Q[c,2cm] Q[c,3cm] Q[c,3cm]}, rowspec={Q[m] Q[m] },
                colsep=3pt,
                row{1}={cmd=\textbf},
            }
            \toprule[blue]
            Type & Code & Pictogramme & Signification \\
            \midrule[blue]
            \SetCell[r=5]{c,m}Dangers physiques &SGH01 & \adjustbox{valign=m}{\ghspic{explos}} & Explosif\\
            & SGH02& \adjustbox{valign=m}{\ghspic{flame}}  & Inflammable\\
            & SGH03& \adjustbox{valign=m}{\ghspic{flame-O}}  & Comburant\\
            & SGH04& \adjustbox{valign=m}{\ghspic{bottle}} & Gaz sous pression\\
            & SGH05& \adjustbox{valign=m}{\ghspic{acid}}  & Corrosif\\
            \midrule[blue]
            \SetCell[r=3]{c,m}Dangers pour la santé & SGH06 & \adjustbox{valign=m}{\ghspic{skull}} & Toxique\\
            & SGH07 & \adjustbox{valign=m}{\ghspic{exclam}} & Danger\\
            & SGH08 & \adjustbox{valign=m}{\ghspic{health}} & Grave danger\\
        \midrule[blue]
        Danger pour l'environnnement & SGH09 & \adjustbox{valign=m}{\ghspic{aqpol}} & Danger pour l'environnement\\
            \bottomrule[blue]
        \end{tblr}
        \caption{Pictogrammes utilisés en chimie}
        \label{tab:picto_chimie}
    \end{table}
    
    \subsection[Panneaux interdiction]{Panneaux interdiction}
    
    \begin{table}[!h]%
        \centering
        \begin{tblr}{
                vspan=even, hspan=minimal,
                colspec={Q[c,2cm] Q[c,3cm] Q[c,5cm]}, rowspec={Q[m] Q[m] },
                colsep=3pt,
                row{1}={cmd=\textbf},
            }
            \toprule[blue]
            Code & Pictogramme & Signification \\
            \midrule[blue]
            P001 & \adjustbox{valign=m}{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{\Isosign{P001}}} & Interdiction générale\\
            P002 & \adjustbox{valign=m}{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{\Isosign{P002}}} & Interdiction de fumer\\
            P003 & \adjustbox{valign=m}{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{\Isosign{P003}}} & Flammes nues interdites\\
            P007 & \adjustbox{valign=m}{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{\Isosign{P007}}} & Interdit aux personnes porteuses d’un stimulateur cardiaque\\
            P008 & \adjustbox{valign=m}{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{\Isosign{P008}}} & Articles métalliques ou montres interdits\\
            P014 & \adjustbox{valign=m}{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{\Isosign{P014}}} & Entrée interdite aux porteurs d’implants métalliques\\
            \bottomrule[blue]
        \end{tblr}      \caption{Quelques panneaux courants d'interdiction}
        \label{tab:panneau_interdiction}
    \end{table}
    
    
    
    \subsection[Panneaux d'avertissement]{Panneaux d'avertissement}
    
    \begin{table}[!h]%
        \centering
        \begin{tblr}{
                vspan=even, hspan=minimal,
                colspec={Q[c,2cm] Q[c,3cm] Q[c,5cm]}, rowspec={Q[m] Q[m] },
                colsep=3pt,
                row{1}={cmd=\textbf},
            }
            \toprule[blue]
            Code & Pictogramme & Signification \\
            \midrule[blue]
            W001 & \adjustbox{valign=m}{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{\Isosign{W001}}} & Interdiction générale\\
            W002 & \adjustbox{valign=m}{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{\Isosign{W002}}} & Matières explosives, risque d’explosion\\
            W003 & \adjustbox{valign=m}{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{\Isosign{W003}}} & Matières radioactives ou radiations ionisantes\\
            W004 & \adjustbox{valign=m}{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{\Isosign{W004}}} &Rayonnement laser\\
            W005 & \adjustbox{valign=m}{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{\Isosign{W005}}} & Radiations non ionisantes\\
            W006 & \adjustbox{valign=m}{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{\Isosign{W006}}} & Champ magnétique\\
            W009 & \adjustbox{valign=m}{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{\Isosign{W009}}} & Risque biologique\\
            W010 & \adjustbox{valign=m}{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{\Isosign{W010}}} & Basses températures, gel\\
            W012 & \adjustbox{valign=m}{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{\Isosign{W012}}} & Électricité\\
            W016 & \adjustbox{valign=m}{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{\Isosign{W016}}} & Matières toxiques\\
            W017 & \adjustbox{valign=m}{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{\Isosign{W017}}} & Surface chaude\\
            W021 & \adjustbox{valign=m}{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{\Isosign{W021}}} & Matières inflammables\\
            W023 & \adjustbox{valign=m}{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{\Isosign{W023}}} & Substances corrosives\\
            W028 & \adjustbox{valign=m}{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{\Isosign{W028}}} & Substances comburantes\\
        \end{tblr}      
        \caption{Quelques panneaux courants d'avertissement}
        \label{tab:panneau_avertissement}
    \end{table}
    
    \subsection[Panneaux d'obligation]{Panneaux d'obligation}
    
    \begin{table}[!h]%
        \centering
        \begin{tblr}{
                vspan=even, hspan=minimal,
                colspec={Q[c,2cm] Q[c,3cm] Q[c,5cm]}, rowspec={Q[m] Q[m] },
                colsep=3pt,
                row{1}={cmd=\textbf},
            }
            \toprule[blue]
            Code & Pictogramme & Signification \\
            \midrule[blue]
            M003 & \adjustbox{valign=m}{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{\Isosign{M003}}} & Protection auditive obligatoire\\
            M004 & \adjustbox{valign=m}{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{\Isosign{M004}}} &Protection oculaire obligatoire\\
            M008 & \adjustbox{valign=m}{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{\Isosign{M008}}} & Protection obligatoire des pieds (chaussure de sécurité)\\
            M009 & \adjustbox{valign=m}{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{\Isosign{M009}}} & Protection obligatoire des mains (gants de protection)\\
            M010 & \adjustbox{valign=m}{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{\Isosign{M010}}} & Protection obligatoire du corps (vêtements de protection)\\
            M013 & \adjustbox{valign=m}{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{\Isosign{M013}}} & Protection obligatoire du visage (visière de protection)\\
            M017 & \adjustbox{valign=m}{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{\Isosign{M017}}} & Protection obligatoire des voies respiratoires\\
            M046 & \adjustbox{valign=m}{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{\Isosign{M046}}} & Sécuriser les bouteilles de gaz\\
        \end{tblr}      
        \caption{Quelques panneaux courants d'obligation}
        \label{tab:panneau_obligation}
    \end{table}
    
    \subsection[Panneaux de sauvetage et de secours]{Panneaux de sauvetage et de secours}
    
    \subsection[Panneaux concernant le matériel ou l'équipement de lutte contre l'incendie]{Panneaux concernant le matériel ou l'équipement de lutte contre l'incendie}
    
    

\end{document}

PS: sorry but the images come from the isosefety package and I don't know how to make my code directly compilable with the images (but the overall form of the document is still bad anyway!)

If you don't want your tables to float, don't use a floating environment like table.

Instead using tblr in table float environments tray to use longtblr, They will split over pages where will be needed. Another way is to insert \clearpage before subsection where needed, but be aware that this will introduce empty spaces before them.

tables are floats, which are called that because LaTeX will float it to where it thinks is best.  See the second highest voted answer of the suggested similar question.  In your case, you have big tables that are the only thing in their section, so the table ends up on the next page and the section headings up on the previous page.  If that's truly your content, I would consider moving the section title into the table caption, and removing the section command altogether.
